pg_rewind: servers diverged at WAL location
We have a primary and one standby as our HA setup for postgres 15.6. we are using repmgr 5.4.1.1 for our HA setup. We were testing a scenario, if a primary goes down, it is able to do automatic failover to standby which eventually went successful. While, making the original primary to rejoin the cluster, we are getting below errors while using node rejoin.
Primary data directory: /pgresdata101/data/
standby data directory: /pgresdata101/standby_db

repmgr -f /opt/postgresql/15.6/bin/repmgr.conf cluster show
 ID | Name          | Role    | Status    | Upstream | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string            
----+---------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | d-dba-pg-0ptt | primary | - failed  | ?        | default  | 100      |          | host=10.29.98.86 port=5432 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
 2  | d-dba-pg-rnh9 | primary | * running |          | default  | 100      | 2        | host=10.29.97.241 port=5432 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2

WARNING: following issues were detected
  - unable to connect to node "d-dba-pg-0ptt" (ID: 1)

command>>repmgr node rejoin -f /opt/postgresql/15.6/bin/repmgr.conf -d 'host=10.29.97.241 port=5432 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr' --force-rewind --config-files=postgresql.conf,postgresql.local.conf,pg_hba.conf -v

NOTICE: using provided configuration file "/opt/postgresql/15.6/bin/repmgr.conf"
DEBUG: server version number is: 150000
DEBUG: set_config():
  SET synchronous_commit TO 'local'
DEBUG: get_primary_node_id():
SELECT node_id                   FROM repmgr.nodes     WHERE type = 'primary'    AND active IS TRUE
DEBUG: get_node_record():
  SELECT n.node_id, n.type, n.upstream_node_id, n.node_name,  n.conninfo, n.repluser, n.slot_name, n.location, n.priority, n.active, n.config_file, '' AS upstream_node_name, NULL AS attached   FROM repmgr.nodes n  WHERE n.node_id = 2
NOTICE: rejoin target is node "d-dba-pg-rnh9" (ID: 2)
DEBUG: connecting to: "user=repmgr connect_timeout=2 dbname=repmgr host=10.29.97.241 port=5432 fallback_application_name=repmgr options=-csearch_path="
DEBUG: set_config():
  SET synchronous_commit TO 'local'
DEBUG: get_recovery_type(): SELECT pg_catalog.pg_is_in_recovery()
DEBUG: get_node_record():
  SELECT n.node_id, n.type, n.upstream_node_id, n.node_name,  n.conninfo, n.repluser, n.slot_name, n.location, n.priority, n.active, n.config_file, '' AS upstream_node_name, NULL AS attached   FROM repmgr.nodes n  WHERE n.node_id = 1
DEBUG: local timeline: 1; rejoin target timeline: 2
DEBUG: get_timeline_history():
TIMELINE_HISTORY 2
DEBUG: local tli: 1; local_xlogpos: 0/9000028; follow_target_history->tli: 1; follow_target_history->end: 0/9000000
NOTICE: pg_rewind execution required for this node to attach to rejoin target node 2
DETAIL: rejoin target server's timeline 2 forked off current database system timeline 1 before current recovery point 0/9000028
DEBUG: guc_set():
SELECT true FROM pg_catalog.pg_settings  WHERE name = 'full_page_writes' AND setting = 'off'
DEBUG: guc_set():
SELECT true FROM pg_catalog.pg_settings  WHERE name = 'wal_log_hints' AND setting = 'on'
INFO: prerequisites for using pg_rewind are met
DEBUG: using archive directory "/tmp/repmgr-config-archive-d-dba-pg-0ptt"
DEBUG: copying "postgresql.conf" to "/tmp/repmgr-config-archive-d-dba-pg-0ptt/postgresql.conf"
WARNING: specified file "/pgresdata101/data/postgresql.local.conf" not found, skipping
DEBUG: copying "pg_hba.conf" to "/tmp/repmgr-config-archive-d-dba-pg-0ptt/pg_hba.conf"
INFO: 2 files copied to "/tmp/repmgr-config-archive-d-dba-pg-0ptt"
NOTICE: executing pg_rewind
DETAIL: pg_rewind command is "/opt/postgresql/pg/bin/pg_rewind -D '/pgresdata101/data' --source-server='host=10.29.97.241 port=5432 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2'"
DEBUG: executing:
  /opt/postgresql/pg/bin/pg_rewind -D '/pgresdata101/data' --source-server='host=10.29.97.241 port=5432 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2' 2>/tmp/repmgr_command.wgVGPS
DEBUG: result of command was 1 (256)
DEBUG: local_command(): output returned was:
pg_rewind: servers diverged at WAL location 0/9000000 on timeline 1
pg_rewind: error: could not open file "/pgresdata101/data/pg_wal/000000010000000000000008": No such file or directory
pg_rewind: error: could not find previous WAL record at 0/802B668

ERROR: pg_rewind execution failed
DETAIL: pg_rewind: servers diverged at WAL location 0/9000000 on timeline 1
pg_rewind: error: could not open file "/pgresdata101/data/pg_wal/000000010000000000000008": No such file or directory
pg_rewind: error: could not find previous WAL record at 0/802B668

